# Contradictory clarification of finite-closed topology (to my wrong eyes at least)

Tags: general-topology

I am studying topology through the *Topology without Tears* book, and on the first unit the finite-closed topology is presented with the following definition:

> 1.3.1
> **Definition**.
> Let $X$ be any non-empty set. A topology $\tau$ on $X$ is called the finite-closed topology or the cofinite topology if the closed subsets
> of $X$ are $X$ and all finite subsets of $X$ ; that is, the open sets are $\emptyset$ and all subsets of $X$ which have finite complements.

Then, there is a note that clarifies a bit more the definition implications:

> Note that Definition 1.3.1 does not say that every topology which has $X$ and the finite subsets of $X$ closed is the finite-closed topology. These must be the only closed sets.

And then puts an example (which is where I am going to bring up my questions):

> 1.3.2 **Example**. If $\Bbb N$ is the set of all positive integers, then sets such as $\{1\}$, $\{5, 6, 7\}$, $\{2, 4, 6, 8\}$ are finite and hence closed in the finite-closed topology. Thus their complements
> $\{2, 3, 4, 5,\ldots\}$, $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10,\ldots\}$, $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, \dots\}$ are open sets in the finite-closed topology. On the other hand, the set of even positive integers is not a closed set since it is not finite and hence its complement, the set of odd positive integers, is not an open set in the finite-closed topology.

**QUESTION:** So, if only the finite subsets of $X$ are closed sets in a finite-closed topology, the topology presented in the example is a bit confusing. Given that $\tau$ is indeed a finite-closed topology, with such sets of the example, then their complements must be open (because they are infinite sets). But the complement of, for example, $\{2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots\}$ is $\{1\}$, which is also in the topology, and so, $\{2, 3, 4, 5,\dots\}$ is closed and open (clopen). Isn't the example showing a topology that isn't a finite-closed topology, or is there something else that I am not understanding?

Comment: "$\{1\}$ ... is also in the topology" Why?

Comment: You should say (and think!) "**the** finite-closed topology" rather than "**a** finite-closed topology", since for each set, this is one concrete topology defined on this set. Moreover, as far as I know, *cofinite* topology is much more common than *finite-closed* topology.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  you might like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883972/explain-the-details-of-constructive-injection-from-the-set-mathbbn-mathbbn)

Comment: @Ulli I still didn't got to that corollary hehe and yeah, online I have seen cofinite more often.

Comment: @NoahSchweber {1} is in the topology as a starting point.

Comment: @pdaranda661 No, it isn't. The topology consists of the complements of the finite sets; at no point does the text say that $\{1\}$ is in the topology. (The text says $\{1\}$ is in the set of *closed* sets, but that's not the same thing at all!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\{1\}$ is finite, thus closed, so its complement $\{2, 3, \ldots\}$ is open. There is no reason to suppose $\{1\}$ is open (and in fact it isn't because its complement is infinite).

Comment: But, as far as I know, a set is open in a topology if it is a member of the topology, and closed if its complement is open in the topology, i.e. if the complement is in the topology.

Comment: @pdaranda661 That is correct. Perhaps your confusions comes from this: You can specify a topology in two ways: either by giving the open sets (the standard way, if you will) or by giving all the closed sets (you obtain the open sets from the closed sets by taking complements). The author here employs the latter method.

Comment: Mmm okay, let me know if the following is right: a closed set in a topology is not necessarily a member of the topology.

Comment: @pdaranda661 That's correct.

Comment: Perfect, from them I think I can more easily understand it. But then, a cofinite topology is composed by (if the set from which we spawn the subsets is X): X, 0, and all the infinite subsets of X, because all the finite subsets of X (and only those) must be closed.

Comment: @pdaranda661 That's not quite correct: it's composed of $X$, $\emptyset$, and _all sets whose complement is finite_. That's why it's called the cofinite topology. For instance, the set of even numbers is not open in $\mathbb{Z}$ with the cofinite topology even though it's infinite: its complement are the odd numbers, another infinite set.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the clarification and your time!